# Syncano - get Objects with reference to particular UserProfile

Tags: android, syncano

I have a class of "work" objects - all have relation to UserProfile class. I want to query for Work objects that are related to local user.
That is why I do:

```
Where<Work> where = new Where<>();
where.eq(Work.FIELD_USERIDID, UserProfile.FIELD_ID, userProfile.getId());
Syncano.getInstance().getObjects(Work.class).setWhereFilter(where).sendAsync(callback);
```

And I get:

```
Response{resultCode=1, httpResultCode=400, error='{"query":"Field userProfile cannot be used in a query as it is not indexed."}', httpReasonPhrase='Bad Request', data=null}
```

What is a correct way to query for classes that have relation to UserProfile and I want only object with relation to particular UserProfile?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, this was quick.
You need to enable Field Fitering on this field (via code(annotation) or Web Dashboard).
http://docs.syncano.io/docs/android#section-fields-filtering
http://docs.syncano.io/docs/data-objects-filtering